# Java socket can client can not read the data

Tags: java, sockets

The client send a message, then the server receives the message and response the message. I don't know why the client can not read the response. If I remove the read part in client, the server can get the message. However for the following code, nothing work. Also I tried the `flush()`, it still doesn't work.

For client

```
public void run() {

    try (Socket echoSocket = new Socket(HOSTNAME, Integer.parseInt(PORTNUMBER));
            DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(echoSocket.getOutputStream());
            DataInputStream dIn = new DataInputStream(echoSocket.getInputStream());
    ) {

        while (true) {


            command = UI.commandQueue.take()
            dOut.writeInt(Message.toByteArray(command).length);
            dOut.write(Message.toByteArray(command));


            int length;
            while((length = dIn.readInt()) != 0) {
            if (length > 0){
                byte[] messagebyte = new byte[length];
                dIn.readFully(messagebyte, 0, messagebyte.length);
                try {
                    msg = Message.fromByteArray(messagebyte);
                    testDisplay(msg);
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                testDisplay(msg);
            }
            }


        }

    }catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        UI.display("Don't know about host " + HOSTNAME);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        UI.display("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to " + HOSTNAME);
    }
}
```

For server

```
public void run() {

    try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(PORT_NUMBER));
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

            DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            DataInputStream dIn = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());) {
        int length;
        while ((length = dIn.readInt()) != 0) {
            if (length > 0) {
                byte[] messagebyte = new byte[length];
                dIn.readFully(messagebyte, 0, messagebyte.length); // read the
                                                                // message
                Message msg;
                try {
                    msg = Message.fromByteArray(messagebyte);
                    testDisplay(msg);
                    dOut.writeInt(Message.toByteArray(msg).length);
                    dOut.write(Message.toByteArray(msg));
                    UI.display("ack sent");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    UI.display(e.getMessage());
                }

            }
            }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        UI.display(
                "Exception caught when trying to listen on port " + PORT_NUMBER + " or listening for a connection");
        UI.display(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: do you need your server to continually receive and send data from multiple clients? I can see many mistakes in your code and I have a solution to you but need to get your feedback first.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is echoing one response per request, but your client is trying to read more than one response per request, which it will never get, so it blocks.